# The figure environment with centering is not centering a small scale Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment

I googled a lot and saw a number of answers on this resource which recommend using the `figure` environment with `centering` for this purpose, but the result is that the picture is shifted far off to the right. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line test lead line.

    \tikzstyle{my} = [
        line width=2pt,
        black,
        rounded corners,
    ]

    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, everynode/.style={transform shape}, transform canvas={scale=0.2}]
    \draw[my]
        (1,0) -- (10,2)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    test trail line test trail line test trail line test trail line test trail line test trail line test trail line test trail line test trail line test trail line.

    \end{document}
```

I tried with and without `everynode/.style={transform shape}` and the result was the same:

[image: centering]

Comment: Try `\leavevmode\begin{tikzpicture}...`

Comment: Welcome! `tranform canvas` tends to screw up the bounding box regardless of the size of the picture. I do not see why you can't just use `scale=0.2` or perhaps `scale=0.2,transform shape` instead.